# Pagination next button not working Using Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Pagination is not working while clicking on next button

Apex Code:

```
/* Date:21/01/2019 Auther:SudhanshuDescription:Account Search input box   * /

public class AccountEmailAlert {
    public Integer rec { get; set; }  
    public Integer tot { get; set; }
    integer count= 0;
    integer totalRecs = 0;
    integer LimitSize= 5;

    public List<wrapAccount> wrapAccountList {get; set;}
    public list <Account> acc {get;set;}
    public String searchKey {get;set;}
    Set<Id> accids = new Set<Id>();
    public AccountEmailAlert( ) {
        tot=totalRecs = [select count() from account];
    }
    public void search(){
        wrapAccountList = new List<wrapAccount>();
        if(searchKey!=null && searchKey!='' && wrapAccountList !=null)
        {
            string searchquery='select Name,id,Type,Rating from account where name like \'%'+searchKey+ '%\'LIMIT:limitsize OFFSET:count';
            acc= Database.query(searchquery); 
            for (Account ac : acc){
                wrapAccountList.add(new wrapAccount(ac));
            }

        }   
        else {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Can not be empty textbox' );
            ApexPages.addmessage(msg);
            clear();  
        }       
    }
    public void clear(){
        wrapAccountList.clear();
    }
    public void sendEmail()
    {   
        if(wrapAccountList != null){
            processSelected();
            if(accids.isEmpty()){
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please select the checkbox'));
            }
            List<Contact> conList=[SELECT Id, Name, Email, AccountId FROM Contact where Accountid IN:accids ];
            system.debug('error'+conList);
            EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Contact Email Templates'];
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for(contact con : conList)
            {            
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
                mail.setTargetObjectId(con.id);
                mail.setReplyTo(con.Email);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                allmsg.add(mail);
            }

            for(wrapAccount wa:wrapAccountList){
                Integer counter= allmsg.size();
                if(counter>0 && wa.selected==true){
                    Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,counter+' ' +'E-mail sent successfuly to related contacts')); 

                    if(counter>0 && wa.selected==false){
                        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'No records selected from checkbox')); 
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        else{
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'You can not send email without fetching records'));
        }
    }

    public void processSelected() {
        acc = new List<Account>();      
        for(wrapAccount wrapAccountObj : wrapAccountList) {
            if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true) {              
                acc.add(wrapAccountObj.acc1);                  
            } 
        }    
        for(Account aa:acc)
        {
            accids.add(aa.id);
        }
    }
    public class wrapAccount {
        public Account acc1 {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public wrapAccount(Account a) {
            acc1 = a;
            selected = false;
        }       
    }

    public PageReference Firstbtn() {
        count=0;
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference prvbtn() {
        count=count-limitsize;
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference Nxtbtn() {
        count=count+limitsize;
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference lastbtn() {
        count= totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,LimitSize);
        return null;
    }
    public Boolean getNxt() {
        if((count+ LimitSize) > totalRecs)
            return true;
        else
            return false;     
    }
    public Boolean getPrv() {
        if(count== 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }  
}
```

Visualforce Code:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountEmailAlert" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
        var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
            if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageMessages id="msg"></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Search box">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputText value="{!searchKey}" />

                <apex:outputPanel style="float:centre">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}" />

                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">          
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapAccountList}" var="a">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.acc1.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.acc1.rating}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.acc1.type}"/>

                <apex:column value="{!a.acc1.id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <div align="center">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                     <apex:commandButton value="send" action="{!sendEmail}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>                
            </div>
            <div align="right">
            <apex:commandButton value="First Page" action="{!Firstbtn}" disabled="{!prv}" reRender="pg1"/>
          <apex:commandButton value="PreviousPage" action="{!prvbtn}" disabled="{!prv}" reRender="pg1"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="NextPage" action="{!Nxtbtn}" disabled="{!nxt}" reRender="pg1"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="LastPage" action="{!lastbtn}" disabled="{!nxt}" reRender="pg1"/>
         </div>

            <apex:outputLabel >Total no of recs:{!tot}</apex:outputLabel>


        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You will have to re-render `PageBlockTable` on click of `CommandButtons`. Currently, it is re-rendering "pg1" which is not present in your page. Set the Id attribute of `PageBlockTable` to "pg1" and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @Vijay Ganji. I have given id as you suggested but 
it is not moving further if i click on next button and no records coming further. what can i do now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make few changes for this to work

- Set the Id of `PageBlockTable` as "pg1"as you are re-rendering "pg1" from `CommandButtons`
- You will have to call the `search` method in all of your action methods which are getting called from `CommandButtons`

So you will have to make below change in your visualforce page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pg1" value="{!wrapAccountList}" var="a">
```

And below changes in your controller

```
public void Firstbtn() {
    count=0;
    search();
}
public void prvbtn() {
    count=count-limitsize;
    search();
}
public void Nxtbtn() {
    count=count+limitsize;
    search();
}
public void lastbtn() {
    count= totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,LimitSize);
    search();
}
```

Comment: P.S. you can change return type to `void` and remove the `return` lines.